# PL SQL loading with exception case study

Tags: plsql

I want to load my target table with an EMPLOYEE table from source.But I don't want the records starting with the alphabet 'A'.How do I do that in PL SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: I tried ENAME <> 'A%'.That does it.Sorry,Its been a really long time since I used PL SQl.Thank you guys.

Comment: That does not. 'AN_EXAMPLE' is not equal to 'A%' but clearly does not fit. `SUBSTR(:value, 1 , 1)` will give you first character, which you can then check.

Answer (score 1):

> Just as simple as it is.

```
INSERT INTO tagert_table
SELECT * FROM SOURCE_TABLE WHERE NAME NOT LIKE 'A%';
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.